# .htaccess Apache mod rewrite rule always giving a redirect loop

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am normally fine at writing apache redirects but this particular client's server has been giving me problems :c

I am trying to redirect all sub-pages to the main domain but I am always getting a infinite redirection loop.

Here's my .htaccess file - what am I doing wrong?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^test$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !"^/$"
RewriteRule ^.*$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

whoa redirect infinity! but say if I do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^test$ "http\:\/\/example\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```

This will redirect http://example.com/test to http://example.com and bam, it works!

Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

// EDIT

The issue is that we have a mailing list plugin which sends the user a confirmation email. After clicking the confirmation button in the confirm email the user is redirected back to our site with a long query string appended to http://example.com/. The query string is generated so it's never going to be the same.

Here's an example of one of the query strings:

```
http://example.com/?has_media=false&fan=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.topspin.net%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Ffan%2Fshow%2F63451204%3Fartist_id%3D12053%26auth%3D96419cab29f59a342cde9ca3c0c20b58&campaign=https%3A%2F%2Fapp.topspin.net%2Fapi%2Fv1%2Fartist%2F12053%2Fcampaign%2F10151864
```

// Edit 2

I tried @Jon Lin's example and the page loads strangely but it does load. Basically, the correct domain loads in some browsers but the assets (CSS, and images do not) and the networks inspector is showing these paths as permanently moved also :s

Comment: show some examples of URLs that you want, original and redirected

Comment: I think the problem is coming from the fact that you're trying to redirect ALL subpages, including the index.php/html which gets redirected to itself for infinity. Might I ask why??

Comment: Are you really trying to rewrite example.com or www.example.com to example.com ? Perhaps all you need to do is remove the first condition

Comment: @PeterKrauss (and Jhecht, and ErstwhileIII) updated my question with more specifics and an example

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your last rule to:

```
RewriteRule !^(?:index\.(html?|php)|)$ http://example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

The reason is that after the directory index is mapped (to something like `index.php`), the rules get reprocessed again, and thus the extra redirect.

Note that the query string is **still** going to be at the end. That's because there is no way to match against the query string in a `RewriteRule`. You need to match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}` variable. In order to get rid of the query string, you need to add a `?` to the end of `http://example.com/`.

Comment: unfortunately, this didn't work for me. I'll update my answer with specifics